# creating segmented table using sequelize.js in Vertica

Tags: javascript, node.js, sequelize.js, vertica

we are using sequelize.js (npm) in order to work with Vertica database to create table for example,
all works fine and my question is -> is there an option to create a table using sequelize.js in vertica so the table may be segmented/not segmented table ?

today we are using define method which works but is there an option to tell to create the table as segmented table for Vertica ?

current code example :

```
        let verticaTable = verticaORM.define(tableName, tableSchema, {
            freezeTableName: false,
            schema: schemaName,
            tableName: tableName,
            timezone: false,
            timestamps: true,
            createdAt: false,
            updatedAt: false
        });
```

is there a flag or another option to keep using sequelize.js to work with vertica but do create the table as segmented table ?

Thanks

Comment: I don't see that sequelize.js supports Vertica officially, are you using pg driver to create the connection?

Comment: i just see that it doesn't really support, is there good NodeJS package to use for working with vertica ?

Comment: Not really. There is this package https://www.npmjs.com/package/vertica. But it isn't maintained, and doesn't support ORM. Maybe use a combination of them: node-vertica for creating the segmented table, sequelize for the rest.